# Possible to set multiple slow log and error log on mysql module filebeat?

Tags: mysql, docker, elasticsearch, filebeat

I have one development server and already installed

- elasticsearch
- kibana
- filebeat
- docker

on docker already running 2 container mariadb database.

I already set filebeat for 1 mariadb database.
with config on `/etc/filebeat/modules.d/mysql.yml` like this

```
- module: mysql
  # Error logs
  error:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/media/dbdev1/data/mysql_error.log"]

  # Slow logs
  slowlog:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/media/dbdev1/data/mysql_slow.log"]
```

if I need more error log and slow log from other container mariadb database is just change `/etc/filebeat/modules.d/mysql.yml` like this

```
- module: mysql
  # Error logs
  error:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/media/dbdev1/data/mysql_error.log","/media/dbdev2/data/mysql_error.log"]

  # Slow logs
  slowlog:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/media/dbdev1/data/mysql_slow.log","/media/dbdev2/data/mysql_slow.log"]
```

my expectation filebeat can pull mysql_error.log from 2 different mariadb container with different path also

some filebeat setup log

```
2021-10-25T10:43:25.616+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:665    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/var/log/filebeat]
2021-10-25T10:43:25.619+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:673    Beat ID: cb340c7a-15b4-44f7-8a66-06f6850c1c0f
2021-10-25T10:43:26.499+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1014   Beat info       {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/etc/filebeat", "data": "/var/lib/filebeat", "home": "/usr/share/filebeat", "logs": "/var/log/filebeat"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "cb340c7a-15b4-44f7-8a66-06f6850c1c0f"}}}
2021-10-25T10:43:26.501+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1023   Build info      {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "5ae799cb1c3c490c9a27b14cb463dc23696bc7d3", "libbeat": "7.15.1", "time": "2021-10-07T22:06:49.000Z", "version": "7.15.1"}}}
2021-10-25T10:43:26.501+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1026   Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":2,"version":"go1.16.6"}}}
2021-10-25T10:43:26.503+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1030   Host info       {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2021-10-25T09:45:23+07:00","containerized":false,"name":"localhost.localdomain","ip":["127.0.0.1/8","::1/128","10.0.2.20/24","fe80::a00:27ff:fe8c:82d0/64","192.168.131.5/24","fe80::a00:27ff:fedd:bb9e/64","172.17.0.1/16","172.18.0.1/16","fe80::42:89ff:fe04:e2cb/64","fe80::2c35:92ff:fe88:4daf/64","fe80::38b2:66ff:fe52:b1ec/64"],"kernel_version":"4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64","mac":["08:00:27:8c:82:d0","08:00:27:dd:bb:9e","02:42:ad:3d:07:6b","02:42:89:04:e2:cb","2e:35:92:88:4d:af","3a:b2:66:52:b1:ec"],"os":{"type":"linux","family":"redhat","platform":"centos","name":"CentOS Linux","version":"8","major":8,"minor":4,"patch":2105},"timezone":"WIB","timezone_offset_sec":25200,"id":"b14f68ad4b8c4732a4cfe379692179ec"}}}
2021-10-25T10:43:26.503+0700    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1059   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":null,"permitted":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read","38","39"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read","38","39"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read","38","39"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/media/dbdev1", "exe": "/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat", "name": "filebeat", "pid": 3503, "ppid": 1941, "seccomp": {"mode":"disabled","no_new_privs":false}, "start_time": "2021-10-25T10:43:23.920+0700"}}}
2021-10-25T10:43:26.503+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:309    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 7.15.1
2021-10-25T10:43:26.504+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:184      Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'filebeat-7.15.1' as ILM is enabled.
2021-10-25T10:43:26.517+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-10-25T10:43:26.521+0700    INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/module.go:113  Beat name: localhost.localdomain
2021-10-25T10:43:26.585+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-10-25T10:43:26.820+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.15.0
2021-10-25T10:43:26.895+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:261      Auto ILM enable success.
2021-10-25T10:43:26.929+0700    INFO    [index-management.ilm]  ilm/std.go:170  ILM policy filebeat exists already.
2021-10-25T10:43:26.929+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:401      Set setup.template.name to '{filebeat-7.15.1 {now/d}-000001}' as ILM is enabled.
2021-10-25T10:43:26.929+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:406      Set setup.template.pattern to 'filebeat-7.15.1-*' as ILM is enabled.
2021-10-25T10:43:26.929+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:440      Set settings.index.lifecycle.rollover_alias in template to {filebeat-7.15.1 {now/d}-000001} as ILM is enabled.
2021-10-25T10:43:26.929+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:444      Set settings.index.lifecycle.name in template to {filebeat {"policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"actions":{"rollover":{"max_age":"30d","max_size":"50gb"}}}}}}} as ILM is enabled.
2021-10-25T10:43:26.974+0700    INFO    template/load.go:229    Existing template will be overwritten, as overwrite is enabled.
2021-10-25T10:43:28.637+0700    INFO    [add_cloud_metadata]    add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go:101    add_cloud_metadata: hosting provider type not detected.
2021-10-25T10:43:31.539+0700    INFO    template/load.go:132    Try loading template filebeat-7.15.1 to Elasticsearch
2021-10-25T10:43:32.442+0700    INFO    template/load.go:124    Template with name "filebeat-7.15.1" loaded.
2021-10-25T10:43:32.442+0700    INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:297      Loaded index template.
2021-10-25T10:43:32.475+0700    INFO    [index-management.ilm]  ilm/std.go:126  Index Alias filebeat-7.15.1 exists already.
2021-10-25T10:43:32.476+0700    INFO    kibana/client.go:167    Kibana url: http://localhost:5601
2021-10-25T10:43:38.391+0700    INFO    kibana/client.go:167    Kibana url: http://localhost:5601
2021-10-25T10:44:58.953+0700    INFO    instance/beat.go:848    Kibana dashboards successfully loaded.
2021-10-25T10:44:58.976+0700    WARN    [cfgwarn]       instance/beat.go:574    DEPRECATED: Setting up ML using Filebeat is going to be removed. Please use the ML app to setup jobs. Will be removed in version: 8.0.0
2021-10-25T10:44:58.993+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-10-25T10:44:59.006+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.15.0
2021-10-25T10:44:59.006+0700    INFO    kibana/client.go:167    Kibana url: http://localhost:5601
2021-10-25T10:44:59.098+0700    WARN    fileset/modules.go:425  X-Pack Machine Learning is not enabled
2021-10-25T10:44:59.207+0700    WARN    fileset/modules.go:425  X-Pack Machine Learning is not enabled
2021-10-25T10:44:59.207+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-10-25T10:44:59.212+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.15.0
2021-10-25T10:44:59.214+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://localhost:9200
2021-10-25T10:44:59.219+0700    INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.15.0
2021-10-25T10:44:59.351+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.15.1-mysql-error-pipeline"}
2021-10-25T10:44:59.480+0700    INFO    [modules]       fileset/pipelines.go:133        Elasticsearch pipeline loaded.  {"pipeline": "filebeat-7.15.1-mysql-slowlog-pipeline"}
2021-10-25T10:44:59.480+0700    INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:262   Loading of config files completed.
2021-10-25T10:44:59.481+0700    INFO    [load]  cfgfile/list.go:129     Stopping 1 runners ...
```

Comment: *"Is this correct?"* - Well, have you tried? What happened?

Comment: already tried but the result only get one mysql_error.log from dbdev1

Comment: What do the filebeat logs say?

Comment: hi already add filebeat setup log on above

Comment: I asked "what do the logs say" and meant "look at them and find out what's going on", not "dump them here". ;) Normally filebeat tells exactly which log files it found before it goes to work. I can't see that part in the log you're showing.

Comment: Other than that, the documentation is pretty clear: *"`var.paths`: An array of glob-based paths that specify where to look for the log files."* ([see](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.2/filebeat-module-mysql.html#_error_log_fileset_settings_3)), so your config file is fine. The error must be something else.

Comment: so filebeat only can pull one logfile in one instance ?

Comment: Huh?! Where did I, or the documentation, say that? That question *directly* contradicts what I said one comment earlier

Comment: no I mean i ask, 

so how to make file beat can pull 2 different log file ?

Comment: Maybe you need to attach a Docker "volume", thereby letting you put the logs in the main system rather than in each Docker instance?

Comment: I got some clue after export the response on kibana at filebeat dashboard mysql 
I see filebeat already got the log error from dbdev2 
` "log.file.path": [
              "/media/dbdev1/data/mysql_error.log"
            ], `
` "log.file.path": [
              "/media/dbdev2/data/mysql_error.log"
            ], `

but I didn't filter on kibana to see between dbdev1 and dbdev2